# Update code to use Linq

Tags: .net, linq, url-rewriting

Are there any tools that could analyze code and suggest rewrites that use Linq?

Comment: LINQ covers several different flavors.  Linq to XML, Linq to Objects, Linq to Sql.  You might provide more information about exactly which flavor AND possibly a code sample of what it is you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper includes some "Upgrade to LINQ" functionality, I've never used it, but it may be useful: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#code_analysis

Comment: There have been a few times where Resharper figured out how to replace 10+ lines of legacy code with a very simple, easy to understand LINQ statement.  There's no way I would have figured that out on my own - Resharper is smarter than me!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - it supports intellisense (paid version) and can express a code fragment you write using various syntaxes.

Comment: LINQPad is great for quickly testing things out.